# cocoon: change where added form field is rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, cocoon-gem

I have a form that uses cocoon to dynamically add form fields.  The problem is with styling.  The form fields are being added in the wrong spot.  Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-5>
    <!--content here !-->
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <!-- more content here !-->
</div>
<%= form_for @owner do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= f.fields_for :cars do |car| %>
            <%= render 'cars_fields', :f => car %>
        <% end %>

        <div class="row text-center center-block">
            <%= f.submit "send", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <%= link_to_add_association f, :cars, class: 'btn bgm-cyan btn-float waves-effect' do %>
            <i class="md md-add"></i>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the code of the partial car_fields:

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding: 10px 40px;" >
    <%= f.text_field :make, class: 'form-control input-sm', placeholder: "Car Make"%>
</div>
```

I want the `link_to_add_association` button to be to the right of the form.  When pressed, I want the new form field to appear inside `col-md-4`.  Instead, it is appearing below all of the content on the page.  How do I make the new form field appear inside `col-md-4`?  i think it has something to do with `data-association-insertion-node` or `data-association-insertion-method` but the documentation has been difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

> `data-association-insertion-node` : the jquery selector of the node. Default: parent node
>
> `data-association-insertion-method` : jquery method that inserts the new data. before, after, append, prepend, etc. Default: before
>
> `data-association-insertion-traversal` : the jquery traversal method to allow node selection relative to the link. closest, next, children, etc. Default: absolute selection

So by using the default traversal method which is `absolute` , you can go for something like this

```
<%= form_for @owner do |f| %>
<div id="place-to-insert" class="col-md-4">
    <%= f.fields_for :cars do |car| %>
        <%= render 'cars_fields', :f => car %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="row text-center center-block">
        <%= f.submit "send", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <%= link_to_add_association f, :cars, class: 'btn bgm-cyan btn-float waves-effect0', data: {association_insertion_method: "append", association_insertion_node: "#place-to-insert"} do %>
        <i class="md md-add"></i>
    <% end %>
</div>
```